# How fix or reinstall Gvim in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, text-editor, gvim

I tried to use my .vimrc file from Windows in Ubuntu 12.04 but i am not having success.
I also pasted the .vimrc file at the native vimrc file at `usr/share/vim` but no success. Tried to create another file like `_vimrc` and checked at my home folder the hidden files but there is no `~/vimrc` or something like that.
So i edited the `/usr/share/vim/gvimrc` and i am having troubles too. The Vim parser reads the code but don't apply the changes and when deleting it gets to much delay.
So i am wondering how to re-install or fix this problem.
I am also having this weird `^M` at the end of files.
So how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

[problem of gvim]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1uS.png

Answer (score 0):

The weird `^M` characters are representations of the carriage return (CR) character, because your pasted text includes Windows-style (CR-LF) line terminations (Unix uses plain LF). You can remove them using the `dos2unix` utility, or try either

```
sed -i 's/\r//' .vimrc
```

or

```
tr -d $'\r' < .vimrc > .vimrc_new
```

and then renaming `.vimrc_new` back to `.vimrc`. It's possible that the line terminations are preventing the .vimrc from being read properly, but there may be other issues.